# Making an existing exe with gui into windows service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

I have a c# project that is more or less a exe file with a GUI ontop to make some settings. The projects purpose is to collect data either when the users forces a collect or when a time has been reached everyday that has been set by the user. There is also an installer project for this, all bundled in VS2010 for .NET 3.0. I would like to take part of my code to be used by windows service. The part that everyday at a given time should perform a collect data operation.

**So my question is, can I do this in the same project or should I create a new project for this? Do I then need to create a new installer or can I have it all installed by the same project? And if so, how? So I more or less asking for tips from anyone who has done the same thing as I'm trying to do.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't already, you should split your code into two projects.  One class library that implements the behaviour/functionality you need, and the other Winform app that references the class lib. project.  Now create a Window Service project that refs. the class lib.  You can then create a new MSI project as the installer for the service.

Also read [intro to windows services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The code is split into GUI and behavior projects. So there will be another project then for the windows service making it 4 porjects in total (behavior, gui, win service and installer). Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.  You might also want a console app that you can use as an entry point when debugging the class lib.

Comment: Good point, but could i not attach VS debugger to my service instead?

Comment: Yes, but you can't just hit F5 in VS to fire it up.