# Configurable Windows Service - How and where to store configuration

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I created a C# application to manage data synchronization between an ERP and a CRM. This application reads a table every 500ms, and sends data via WebService to CRM. 
For the moment, I have two screens for my application : a first to configure connections (ERP's DB connection informations and CRM's URL and WS Token), a second with a start button to launch the loop thread.

I know want my application to be nothing more than a windows service installer. What I want to do is to launch my application, configure ERP and CRM connections, and then click on a 'Install' button. When this button is clicked, a service is created and makes the same work that my application makes now when i click the 'start' button.

I already read those links [Converting my application in a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16166812/2806497),  [Making an existing exe with gui into windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8968944/2806497) and of course http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

Here is my question :

How to make a configurable windows service ? I think the simplest way is to store configuration into files that utility and service would share. Where to store those files ? The utility must be able to find these files afterwards : registry ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common practice in .NET to store application's or service's settings in this [relative path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`

Comment: But in this case, will my utility be able to access services configuration files stored in ApplicationData ? Can i store them as i want, i mean in a folder and with a name I specified ? Any rights issues ?

Comment: This folder is specially designed for such things and you mustn't encounter any rights issues. Almost all third-party applications store their data there. `Path.Combine(new String[] {
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
@"/YourServiceFolderName"})` is the directory you can save the settings into. Do not forget to create it before accessing ;)

Comment: Oh, thank you for those informations. Last question : since the services configuration won't be user-dependent, should I use CommonApplicationData instead of ApplicationData ?