# Saving Complex User Settings in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I'm writing a little tool to connect to a MS SCOM Server and add subcriptions for monitoring alerts. How ever, I want to save the connection and subscription settings somwhere/some how. Here is the rough structure

```
public class ConnectionManager
{
    ...
    public BindingList<Connection> Connections // All the connection we know
    ...
}
```

Then we have the connections. Basicly this class saves the needed connection fields like Server Name, User Domain, connects to the server, keeps the connection alive etc etc

```
public class Connection
{
    ...
    public string Name;                               // the name of this connection
    public string ServerName;                         // the scom server name
    public string UserDomain;                         // the domain, NETBIOS or FQDN
    public BindingList<Subscription> Subscriptions;   // The subscriptions for this connection
    ...
}
```

Finally, the connection class has Alert Criterias. Alert criterias are basically some kind of regular expressions. The are currently only "extended" (just a string) but I'm going to build simple expression which are going to be build on the fly. It will look like this

```
public class Subscription
{
    ...
    public string ExtededExpression;                        // if not empty, use this
    public BindingList<CriteriaOperator> SimpleOperators;   // otherwhise build a regular expression from this stuff
    ...
}
```

with another subclass

```
public class CriteriaOperator
{
    ...
    public string Field;                  // The field, g.g. LastModified
    public LogicalOperator Operator;      // The logical operator, e.g. LIKE
    public string CompareFieldTo;         // A regular expression, e.g. "%SQL%"
    ...
}
```

And now my question: What do you think is the best way to save such a structure? I'm new to .NET so I'm not sure: Use the Application Settings? Or serialze/deserialize this structure with a XML Serializer? Or write some wrapper classes and then use a XML Serializer? Or is there maybe a completely other approach?

Thanks for help!

Comment: In my opinion the best approach is to create your own custom configuration section http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

Comment: Really depends on the scenario. I disagree with Yevgeniy on using configuration sections as it sounds like this may be a "pr. user setting"... (I know your probably only have one user pr. installation, yet still)... Serialization is usually a decent approach IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend **NOT TO use ApplicationSettings**. IMHO ApplicationsSettings is to store and reload your UI state e.g. the last 10 used files in a text editor or "do not show this message again" for the **specific user**!

If you are thinking of a load/save scenario I do recommend **to create a single class to store all fields needed to save your application state**. **Do not directly store some of your logic** classes with serialization it will mess up things and reduce your maintainability.

By using one single save item you have all your load/store actions centralized in one place.

So...

```
public class SaveItem
{
    // ----------------------------------------------
    // version 1.02:
    public bool New { get; set; }
    public string VeryNew { get; set; }

    // ----------------------------------------------
    // version 1.01:

    public bool Bugfix { get; set; }
    public List<string> AList { get; set; } 

    public SaveItem()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public bool TrySave(string fullFilePath)
    {
        bool result = false;
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fullFilePath);
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveItem));
        try
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, this);
            result = true;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                textWriter.Close();
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static bool TryLoad(string fullFilePath, out SaveItem saveItem)
    {
        bool result = false;
        saveItem = new SaveItem();
        TextReader textReader = null;
        try
        {
            textReader = new StreamReader(fullFilePath);
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveItem));
            saveItem = (SaveItem)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            if (saveItem != null)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            if (saveItem != null)
            {
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (textReader != null)
            {
                textReader.Close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: That is what I intentionally tought to do. Now, I wrote some wrapper classes and de/serialize them save and load the data structure. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, for that purposes you should:

- Write a **singleton** class ([here](http://developersblog.tk/singleton-pattern-global-variable-alternative/) is a great article about it on my blog) for handling settings.
- Use binary or XML **serialization** - as it is easy and customizable
- Save the settings to generic path, I have already answered [where to store it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972495/configurable-windows-service-how-and-where-to-store-configuration/19973580#19973580)

Comment: Thanks for the hind with the user's folder! Works fine